# Passing parameters from ui from to another QT

Tags: c++, qt, point-cloud-library

I want to pass a pclVisualizer object from the mainWindow form class to a new from class to show a new viewport...
but, i have some errors

### viewport.h file :

```
#ifndef VIEWPORT_H
#define VIEWPORT_H

// Qt includes.
#include <QWidget>

// Pcl includes.
#include <pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h>

// Vtk includes
#include <QVTKWidget.h>

/** Ui namespace */
namespace Ui {
class ViewPort;
}// End of Ui namespacce.

/** Viewport class Definition*/
class ViewPort : public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT

  public:
  // Passing visualizer to the new form.
  explicit ViewPort(pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::Ptr, QWidget *parent 
  = 0);
~ViewPort();

private:
  pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::Ptr m_pclViewer;
  Ui::ViewPort *ui;
  QVTKWidget *  m_vtkWidget;
};

#endif // VIEWPORT_H
```

### viewport.cpp file:

```
#include "viewport.h"
#include "ui_viewport.h"

ViewPort::ViewPort(pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::Ptr viewer, QWidget 
*parent) :
QWidget(parent),
ui(new Ui::ViewPort),
viewer(new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer("PCL Visualizer", true)
{
ui->setupUi(this); // error 1
m_vtkWidget = new QVTKWidget;
ui->verticalLayout_pclVisualizer->addWidget(m_vtkWidget);
m_vtkWidget->SetRenderWindow(viewer->getRenderWindow());
} // error 2

ViewPort::~ViewPort()// error 3
{
  delete m_vtkWidget;
  delete ui;
}// error 4
```

and i have some errors in cpp file:

- > error 1 : error: C2059: syntax error: ';'
- > error 2 : error: C3329: syntax error: expected ')' not '}'
- > error 3 : error: C2612: trailing 'qualified-name' illegal in base/member

  initializer list

> error 4 : error: C2612: trailing 'qualified-name' illegal in base/member initializer list

Comment: Close the parenthesis at the end of this line: `viewer(new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer("PCL Visualizer", true))`

Comment: Oh god, What a mistake. :) , thanks too much.